# Magento 2 .htaccess file missing in pub folder

Tags: magento2, .htaccess, filesystem

I was recently trying to upgrade my Magento 2.2.7 to Magento 2.3.0 and the following message came up in component dependencies

```
Found non-writable path(s):
/var/www/vhosts/powermyself.com/httpdocs/pub/.htaccess
```

Upon closer inspection it would seem that the .htaccess file is missing in this folder (although there is still one in pub/static).

Is there any way to get this file back?

Comment: Copy it from  https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/pub/.htaccess

Comment: Thanks. Will I need branch 2.3-develop or 2.2?

Comment: it depends on your version if it's 2.3 then copy from 2.3

Comment: My version is 2.2.7, so should I copy from 2.2?

Comment: Yes, copy it from 2.2 .

Comment: That's great thank you the error is no longer showing. Could you add this as the answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy `.htaccess` file from github repository.

Copy it from https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/pub/.htaccess

If you have already upgraded to version 2.3, you will need .htaccess file of new version i.e 2.3 otherwise download from 2.2.